# CLGeocoder Only Returning One Placemark

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, clgeocoder

I have a problem with CLGeocoder where when I call `geocodeAddressString:withCompletionHandler` I only ever get one result back, despite knowing that the inputted string should return more than one value. The class reference even states:

> In the case of forward-geocoding requests, multiple placemark objects may be returned if the provided information yielded multiple possible locations.

However, my placemarks array only ever has one item in it:

```
    [geocoderDestination geocodeAddressString:destination completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error){
NSLog(@"array count:%i", [placemarks count];}
```

Thank you for any help.

---

I have used strings such as "Piccadilly, UK", "Union Street, UK" which have only returned one result. Now that I think about it, putting UK on the end might be the contributing factor.

Comment: you can add your sample string, so that others can test for themselves

Comment: Done, but I think I've realised my error now hahaha. But the problem is that I need the results to be UK specific, and using geocodeAddressString:inRegion: is not very good as you have to assign a radius, so some of Ireland would be included.

Comment: Well this is taking the piss, even if I use CLLocationDistance distance1 = 750;
    
    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.825564, -2.421976) radius:distance1 identifier:nil]; with geocodeAddressString:inRegion: then it gives me some place in Australia for "Piccadilly".

Answer (score 4):

I dont know about CLGeocoder but if your requirement is a location search another way is to use google location search url http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=london which returns a json containing the matched location information.

Comment: Thanks, I will use that in the meantime as I still can't get this working

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `UK` use `United Kingdom` it will give you some related result.

Try to add some more info in your address.
 
One more thing `UK` is not a valid country code it's `GB` but it seems that putting `GB` instead of `UK` didn't solve the problem.

Moreover `CLGeocoder` is not as smart as `Google Maps API` right now because apple uses its own server to decode addresses so you can use Google services.